# Copper (II) oxide during CuSO4 electrolysis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

I was performing copper (II) sulfate electrolysis (graphite electrodes; 10V; 0,01A) today and I observed black precipitate falling from around cathode. I suppose it's copper(II) oxide. I couldn't find information about this reaction. Have you ever read somewhere about this reaction or do you know it?

Comment: How do you know this is not graphite, to begin with?

Comment: I thought about it but I used the same electrode in the electrolysis of a few solutions and precipitate occurred only when copper was reduced. I used it as a cathode in the electrolysis of dilute hydrochloric acid when it could be mechanically damaged by hydrogen bubbles (the same voltage) and nothing happened. I am aware that graphite electrodes decay but in this case, it seems to fast and as I mentioned occurred only in this solution.

Comment: When done without proper procedures, electrochemical reduction  of copper salts produce copper as a fine dust. Under water and in presence of air this dust easily oxidizes, forming black copper oxide.